# Move the bottom tip of a tooltip

Tags: user-interface, tooltip, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this particular case of an uib-tooltip:

[image]

As it can be seen here, the icon that shows the tooltip is much more on the right while the black triangle under the tooltip is on the middle of it.

I was wondering if it is a way to move that triangle to be right above the icon. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `tooltip-placement` option?

For your example, I would guess that `tooltip-placement="top-right"` should do what you'd like.

[image]

```js
var test = angular.module('test', ['ui.bootstrap']);

angular.bootstrap(document.documentElement, [test.name]);
```

```css
div.wrapper {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
span {
  margin-left: 50px;
  cursor: default;
}
.adjusted {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.default {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://origin2.jsdelivr.net/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.3.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://origin2.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
</head>


<body>
 <div id="chart"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <span uib-tooltip="Default placement"
        class="default">TOP default tooltip
  </span>
  <span uib-tooltip="Placement adjusted."
        tooltip-placement="top-right"
        class="adjusted">
        TOP-RIGHT tooltip
  </span>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```